# jupyter - widgets.DatePicker to convert to proper data format in python pands

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I am using `widgets.DatePicker` in jupyter and populating date as dd-mm-yyyy, however the `date.value` is returning as yyyy-mm-dd format.

I need to convert this to dd-mm-yyyy format, I tried below and many other but failed.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(date.value, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Its not working, any suggestion

Error - `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date`

Comment: Can you explain more what mean failed? There is some error?

Comment: Error - TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date , I am importuing date.time@ jezrael

Comment: `date.value.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`? since you already have a datetime.date object, you should be able to convert to string directly.